# undefined is not function when using multiple, after select multi dates and show DatePickerModal again in react-native-paper-dates

Tags: typescript, react-native, datetimepicker

Error "undefined is not function" when using multiple, after select multi dates and show DatePickerModal again. Im using "react-native-paper-dates"

```
  const [showDate, setShowDate] = useState(false);
  const [dates, setDates] = useState<any>([]);

  <DatePickerModal
    locale="en"
    mode="multiple"
    visible={showDate}
    onDismiss={() => setShowDate(false)}
    dates={dates}
    onConfirm={dates => {
      console.log(dates);
      setShowDate(false);
      setDates(dates);
    }}
  />
```

[image]

Here is my full code:
I dont know how to fix because it happen in library "react-native-paper-dates".
Anyone can help me. Thanks so much

---

I fixed it by add 2 useCallback function onDismiss and onConfirm for DatePickerModal!

```
  const onDismiss = useCallback(() => {
    setShowDate(false);
  }, [setShowDate]);

  const onConfirm = useCallback((params: any) => {
    setShowDate(false);
    setDates(params.dates);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not incredibly clear from the [react-native-paper-dates documentation](https://web-ridge.github.io/react-native-paper-dates/docs/date-picker/multiple-dates-picker) but the value it passes to your `onConfirm` callback is a [structure containing `.dates`](https://github.com/web-ridge/react-native-paper-dates/blob/df216399b0f84770959bd5cf9d0fc902020dce4f/src/Date/Calendar.tsx#L61) rather than just an array of dates:

```js
export type MultiConfirm = (params: { dates: Date[] }) => void
```

Your existing `onConfirm` callback just needs a little change:

```js
    onConfirm={params => {
      console.log(params);
      setShowDate(false);
      setDates(params.dates);
    }}
```

Typescript can actually spot this type of problem – rather than calling `useState<any>` you could specify your expected type:

```js
  const [dates, setDates] = useState<Date[]>([]);
```

With this stronger type specified, Typescript shows an error on your original callback:

```
Argument of type '{ dates: Date[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Date[]>'.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help, but i fixed with create 2 useCallback function onDismiss and on Confirm.